# How to add a new column with check constraint to an table with a single ALTER table statement?

Tags: sql-server

I am writing a small tool that generates some SQL statements for me. The statements looks like this:

```
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON;
BEGIN TRANSACTION x;

ALTER TABLE schema.MyTable ADD MyNewColumn INT DEFAULT(-7777);

--ALTER TABLE schema.MyTable ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_MyTable_MyNewColumn CHECK(MyNewColumn IN(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));

EXEC sp_addextendedproperty @name = N'MS_Description', @value = 'texttexttext',  
@level0type = N'Schema',   @level0name = 'schema',
@level1type = N'Table',    @level1name = 'MyTable',
@level2type = N'Column',   @level2name = 'MyNewColumn';

INSERT INTO schema.SomeOtherTable VALUES(1, 2, 3);
-- Other statements....

--ROLLBACK TRANSACTION x;
--COMMIT TRANSACTION x;
```

Table names and stuff like that comes from the tools interface. the line with the `ADD CONSTRAINT` fails with `invalid column 'MyNewColumn'`... I think thats because of the uncomitted transaction... But I need that if some of the other statements fails, the column, the constraint and the other data should be removed...

So... Is there a way to `ADD` a new column to an existing table and also `ADD` a named `CHECK CONSTRAINT` to the same table in a single statement? Or do you have other ideas how to tackle this?

Comment: Try and have a look at nested transactions. You can open one large transaction, then inside it one transaction where you commit schema changes, commit or rollback, then open a 2nd transaction to add your data, commit or rollback. BEGIN TRAN Top_Tran BEGIN TRAN Schema_Chg COMMIT TRAN Schema_Chg BEGIN TRAN Data_Ins COMMIT TRAN Data_Ins.

Comment: Transactions won't help here, @RaduGheorghiu , it's a compile error; the Transaction will never be started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not due to an uncommitted transaction but because the entire batch must be compiled before execution and the column referenced in the DDL does not yet exist.

To avoid the error, you could add the column and constraints in a single statements:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable
     ADD MyNewColumn INT DEFAULT(-7777)
    ,CONSTRAINT CHK_MyTable_MyNewColumn CHECK(MyNewColumn IN(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
```

If your tooling doesn't support this construct, you'll either need to execute the statements in separate batches or within the same batch using dynamic SQL like:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable
     ADD MyNewColumn INT DEFAULT(-7777);
EXECUTE(N'ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_MyTable_MyNewColumn CHECK(MyNewColumn IN(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));');
```

Also, I suggest you remove `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON;` since you already have an explict transaction in the script. Otherwise, you'll still have an uncommitted transaction after the `COMMIT`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding more context to my comment: *"To affect a column (i.e. `INSERT` into it, add an extended property, etc, etc), it needs to be in a different batch. Even committing the transaction won't change that. Prior to that batch being completed, you will not be able to do "things" to that column. [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c09e65ea1b18cddb180a496ada976c76)"*

My statement is actually wrong here. The reason the error you're getting occurs is because the batch that the column is added, and then attempted to be inserted into (or add the the `CONSTRAINT`) actually fails. The compiler parses the SQL and see that you are attempting to `INSERT` into (add a `CONSTRAINT` to) a column that doesn't **currently** exist, and so fails.

Take this example:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable (ID int);
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable ADD MyColumn int DEFAULT (100);

INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable
VALUES(1,100);
```

This fails with the error below:

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

If you name the columns, however, you get a different error:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable ADD MyColumn int DEFAULT (100);

INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable  (ID, MyColumn)
VALUES(1,100)
```

> Invalid column name 'MyColumn'.

For the SP `sp_addextendedproperty` however, the checking of the existance of the column is deferred until the SP is executed; at which point the column *will* exist. If you try the below, you do *not* get an error:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable (ID int);
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable ADD MyColumn int DEFAULT (100);

EXEC sp_addextendedproperty @name = N'MS_Description', @value = 'texttexttext',  
                            @level0type = N'Schema',   @level0name = 'dbo',
                            @level1type = N'Table',    @level1name = 'MyTable',
                            @level2type = N'Column',   @level2name = 'MyColumn';

GO
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable  (ID, MyColumn)
VALUES(1,100)

GO

DROP TABLE dbo.MyTable;
```

As for your `CONSTRAINT`, this suffers the same problem as the `INSERT`. It needs to be in a separate batch.

One way you could do this is to defer the compiling of the statement adding the `CONSTRAINT` as well, using `sp_executesql`:

```
ALTER TABLE schema.MyTable ADD MyNewColumn INT DEFAULT(-7777);

EXEC sp_executesql N'ALTER TABLE schema.MyTable ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_MyTable_MyNewColumn CHECK(MyNewColumn IN(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));';
```

Comment: sorry that I only can accept one answer since you both posted information that helped me solving the problem :(

Comment: No worries, @Michael . You can always upvote other answers you found helpful as well.